# Menus in outlook webaddin

Tags: c#, office365, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2022, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an outlook web add-in using Visual studio javascript, which will basically have menus like,

```
Main menu-
    Menu 1.1 -(1 Level)
        Menu 1.1.A
        Menu 1.1.B
    Menu 1.2
        Menu 1.2.A(2 Level)
            Menu 1.2.A.A1
            Menu 1.2.A.A2
        Menu 1.2.B
    Menu 1.3
    Menu 1.4
```

I am not able to find any example regarding this, these menus are basically links to external websites. If anyone can share example regarding this or sample xml that would be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Submenus aren't supported in Outlook add-ins, but you can create a menu control in the ribbon to run a function or open a task pane (see the "Drop-down menu" section of [Add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#drop-down-menu)). Then, you could consider adding the other external links to the task pane. For more information on how to implement the menu control, see [Control element of type Menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/manifest/control-menu).